# Android app keeps asking for "Offline Access" permission

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have implemented Google sign-in in my Android app and everything works as expected except that app always asks for "Offline Access" every time user launches the app. I have seen apps like asana which asks for permission only once and then the permission dialog never comes up. I am using the following code to get the token and send that token across to backend.

```
scope = "oauth2:server:client_id:" + SERVER_CLIENT_ID + ":api_scope:" + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN"
token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(NewLoginScreenActivity.this, mEmail, scope);
```

First of all, why is offline access permission coming up when my app is online only app.? Is there anything that I need to do it on client side or this should be fixed on Google dev console.? I am using Play-Services library to get the token.

Comment: remove Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN  and it will stop asking for offline access.  That's what Google calls login